# How to solve this error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js, angular-social-login

I have this function defined:

```
// /middleware/authMiddleware.js 
'use strict'

const jwt = require('jwt-simple');
const moment = require('moment');
require('dotenv').config();


function isAuth(req,res, next) {
    if(!req.headers.authorization) {
        return res.status(403).send({mesagge: 'No tienes autorización'})
    }

    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    const payload = jwt.decode(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_TOKEN);

    if(payload.exp <= moment().unix()) {
        return res.status(401).send({message: 'El token ha expirado'})
    }

    req.user = payload.sub;
    next();
}

module.exports = isAuth
```

And when I call it from the /route/index.js

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const authMiddleware  = require ('../middleware/authMiddleware');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/exito', authMiddleware.isAuth,  (req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).send({token: req.user})
});

module.exports = router;
```

I get the error

```
Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
```

But I don't understand where is the error, I have read some similar question here but I don't know where is the problem.

Thanks.

Oskar

Answer (score 1):

You're directly exporting the function `isAuth` in your `authMiddleware` module which is why in your `index.js` module `authMiddleware` refers to the function itself and `isAuth` obviously does not exist on the function.

In order to fix this, change your router to the following:

```
router.get('/exito', authMiddleware,  (req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).send({token: req.user})
});
```

Comment: Happy to help! Don't forget to accept the answer ;)